# using c4droid for network programming

Tags: android, c, sockets, network-programming

I am in huge trouble. 
I have to use c4droid to create code about network programming. My problem is that when i create a normal socket, terminal of c4droid gives me "operation not permitted". I think the problem is because my cell doesn't have root permission:in fact, the function "geteuid()" gives me number 10133.
So i want to ask if anyone has used c4droid for this type of applications and how it did. You would give me a big help. Thanks so much

Comment: ok guys, i rooted my cell and c4droid seems to work fine. How can i close this question?

Comment: Answer it providing relevant info on resolving the issue. For the reference please look at [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).